Report Viewer Configuration Error when using NGINX proxy_pass to IIS 10 server
I have create a ASP.net webform with a reportview control. Tested this on the IIS server and working 100%. I then, on our linux box changed the NGINX config, added a proxy_pass pointing to the IIS website hosting the asp.net form. On the linux box, is hosted a Net core 3.1 website. In this website there is an IFrame that points to the asp.net webform address. When the IFRame gets loaded, I keep getting below error - please remember it is working on IIS.
The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.
So the issue is now why does NGINX not properly read the web.config and display the control properly.


I have tested with default.aspx end the css files does not get properly loaded.
Help would be much appreciated.

I had resolved the red block error above by using nginx sub_filter. But I have the issue now I cannot downlod the TTF files from Reportsviewer requestes, as sub_filter keep missing the with the replace string.
sub_filter 'href="/TelkomBilling/' 'href="';
sub_filter 'src="/TelkomBilling/' 'src="';

You can check your web.config for handlers registered or not for ReportViewer.

Hi Samwu, in the web.config all handlers is registered. It is working 100% on IIS, but as soon as use NGINX in proxy forward then the issues start happening. I have to use NGINX as we do not want to open the Internet to the IIS server so we have to use an iframe and point to the IIS server internally. Because of the virtual directory "Telkombilling", IIS is pointing all href and src to this virtual address that does not exist when using NGINX Proxy_pass, hence all issues.
